# addSubview dont recognize IBAction

Tags: swift, swift4.2

I have a view controller that presents another view controller, with present, before presenting it:

(code)

when I later try to use that subview I have problems because I do not find the IBAction of the buttons in the subview

```
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        let vcEvent = UIStoryboard(name: "Detail", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "eventDetail") as! EventDetailVC

        vc.viewDetail?.addSubview(vcEvent.view)

        vc.cover?.image = DataManager.shared.arrayImage[indexPath.row]

        self.view.frame = (vc.viewDetail?.bounds)!

        DataManager.shared.cover = DataManager.shared.arrayImage[indexPath.row]

        //DataManager.shared.cover = DataManager.shared.arrayImage[indexPath.row]
    }

    present(vc, animated: true) {
        //NOPE
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing `addChildViewController` before `addSubview` to view.

```
vc.addChildViewController(vcEvent)
vc.viewDetail?.addSubview(vcEvent.view)
...
```

Comment: thx work before the present, but after i have this problem: 

 let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Detail", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "EventAchivments") as! EventAchivmentsVC
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.viewDetail?.addSubview(vc.view)
        }

Comment: In this case you can also use this like self.addChildViewController(vc)

Comment: oh thx so much, i have last question :) i present more subview in same view, how i can dismiss this subview when i present other one ? i try removefromSubview but dosn't work well, i need try now maybe can work after this fix?

Comment: Also, do not forget to use "removeFromParentViewController()" to remove the receiver from its parent's children controllers array

Comment: but how i dismiss the controller ? (in viewDetail) because i load tree view controller (event, map, ach) in the same view (viewDetail)

Comment: load with addSubview i think is wrong how i load the three view controller in subView and load only one at a time when I need it?

Comment: you can use 'presentViewController' OR 'pushViewController' instead of adding subview, why you are adding subview on same view again and again

Comment: the problem is i have a view controller with a view and inside a view i present other view controller

Comment: You can also try UIContainerView for the same

Comment: I wanted to ask you by chance we can hear by email or Skype? I would like to learn more

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185889/discussion-between-nikksindia-and-andrea-di-francia).